# Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers on fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

1. I google two days and still this message. I use debug key to debug
   on my nexus 7.
2. I don't know where is wrong. I have right key,open right api access
3. but google map on my tablet still blank.

MapsFragment:

> ```
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
> ```
>
> Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>   View rootView =
>   inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment,container, false);
>         container.removeAllViews();         map =
>   ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity()
>       .getSupportFragmentManager()
>       .findFragmentById(R.id.map))
>       .getMap();
>       map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
>       map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
>
> ```
>    mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
>    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
> ```
>
> getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map,mMapFragment);
>   fragmentTransaction.commit();         return rootView;    }

Manifest:

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="14"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
>
> <!-- Google Map -->   <permission
>       android:name="com.jertt.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
>       android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="com.jertt.yummymap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
> ```
>
> ```
> <!-- end -->
>
> <uses-feature
>     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
>     android:required="true" />
>
> <!-- end -->
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.jertt.yummymap.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>
>     <!-- Google Map API Key -->
>
>     <meta-data
>         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
>         android:value="AIzaSyB54eZnUp8Sw*****" />
>
>     <!-- end -->
> </application>
> ```

map_fragment.xml

> ```
> <fragment
>     android:id="@+id/map"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
> ```

Comment: keep the original post the same put the edit part under the edit section so that it will not mislead others who visit the post.

Comment: Sorry,But I change my MainActicity,so the problem is different.

Comment: new problem should be posted as a new question. its entirely different from your previous question. the answers will also mislead others as to the original question posted the answers were posted.

Comment: also your still using `SupportMapFragment` and `getSupportFragmentManager()` in your `oncreateView` while you have this `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` in xml

Comment: Sorry,I reverse to past version and ask new question now.

Comment: thanks for understand. i am sure someone can solve your problem good luck. and if the answer posted helps pls accept the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your problem or not, but I spend a TON of time trying to figure this one out.  Checking the permissions, regenerating api keys.  Finally saw a small comment in another answer that worked for me.

Rename your debug.keystore file and then do a clean, and then build.  this will generate a new debug.keystore.  and a new SHA1 fingerprint.  Plug that new fingerprint into the api console and try again.

The other thing you can check is to look at the "reports" section of the api console for the project you are trying to access the api from.  If you have tried to run your project and have no traffic for that api, chances are either the SHA1 fingerprint or the package name you gave is wrong.  In my case it was the fingerprint.

Comment: I don't know whether it has solved someone else problem or not but has solved my problem. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

Your min sdk is 14. No need to use `SupportMapFragment`. Use `MapFragment`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.

```
<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

ALso

```
  GoogleMap  mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                .getMap();
```

Also missing permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Make sure you have followed all the steps @

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Edit: From the comment

Quoting from the docs

Use `MapFragment` class only if you are **targeting API 12** and above. **Otherwise, use SupportMapFragment.**

Comment: But if I want to run both on android 2.3.3, 4.2.2~ I should use supportMapFragment right?

Comment: @user2585728 for that you will have to change your min sdk also which is right now 14. If your min sdk is below 11 use support map fragment

Comment: I change it to MapFragment. But  fragmentTransaction.add  show error:The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, MapFragment)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. check the fragments docs

Answer (score 0):

you have to change to this:

```
GoogleMap  mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                            .getMap();
```

and also include library to manifest file:

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />
```